# Disable Modal backdrop in React Rodal

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

I am using Rodal package for implementing modal feature in one of my projects, now I want to disable the backdrop of the modal on click outside in the background of the modal. how can I achieve that? here is the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/rodal

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: no it did not work with Rodal, can you please give any other solution?

Comment: Were you getting any error or other issues? Also, Can you share your code? may be a fiddle? So that I can take a look.

Comment: here is the fiddle, please give me a solution based on Rodal
https://jsfiddle.net/oaspxuzq/

Comment: Can you please provide [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? There is so much of code and also there are some errors in the fiddle.

Comment: here is what I can do so far, if it does not run successfully could you please point out where I am making mistakes
https://jsfiddle.net/ashfaqrafi/oaspxuzq/1/

Comment: Have you tried with that minimal example on your PC, whether it's working or not? Because it won't run on jsfiddle as `Rodal` is not available from any cdn.

Comment: I tried with you example on my device but it works on Bootstrap Modal but not in React Rodal in my code, as there are my code given could you please say where can I add some code to disable backdrop seeing my version of code?

Comment: When you click outside the modal, does `hideModal()` get executed? Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: no hideModal() does not get executed while I click in the outside

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of any then, may be if you want you can use react-bootstrap modal.

Comment: There is a prop called `showMask` in `Rodal`. You can pass it as `false` and it will work. I tried it on my machine and it works perfectly.

Comment: it worked in my project also but now the backdrop grey color is not there, its become transparent now, don't looks like a modal. could you give any insight onto it?

Comment: That is why I've provided you the second solution. Try 2nd one. Just make sure that in 2nd solution you don't pass `showMask` as prop.

Comment: yes done that, now working fine, thanks a lot Hardik Modha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: Starting from Rodal v1.5.1, we can pass a prop `closeMaskOnClick` to prevent modal from closing. For more information see [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rodal#props).

---

**For older versions of Rodal**:

When you click on `close` or `ok` button, event will be fired and your `hide` function will be called. Similarly, when you click outside the modal, `hide` function will also be called, which will set the state variable `visible` to false and your modal will be hidden.

```
hide(){
   this.setState({ visible: false });
}
```

There are two ways to prevent this.

1. There is a prop called `showMask` in `Rodal`, You can pass it as `false`.

Like this,

```
<Rodal visible={this.state.visible} showMask={false} onClose={this.hide.bind(this)}>
   ....
</Rodal>
```

But passing it as false will not show mask. So there is also another way.

2. You can slightly modify your `hide` function to check whether it was called after clicking on the `ok` or `close` button or it was called as a result of any click event outside your modal.

You can check:

```
hide(event){
   if (event.target.className === 'rodal-mask') {
       return;
   }
   this.setState({ visible: false });
}
```

I've tested both the methods on my machine and it works perfectly. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Rodal version 1.5.1 you can simply set the `closeMaskOnClick`option to false.